# iPhone: Convert NSString (unicode string) to char array and reverse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unicode, nsstring

I have a unicode string like that @"anh sẽ đến". Now I want to cut it to a char array, and then I want to join it in one string and show it on the screen. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because literals are objects, you can use `[@"anh sẽ đến" UTF8String]` to get it to a char array, and `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` for char to NSString conversions, though to be honest, it would probably be easier to just use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:@"anh sẽ đến%c", myUnichar]` than to go back and forth between string containers.

Comment: I do it look like that
const char *c = [@"anh sẽ đến" UTF8String];
NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:&c[i-1]]; 
tempPlayedStr = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@%@",tempPlayedStr,tempStr];

but it still not work

Comment: Because you appear to be pointing to your char array twice (once to dereference, once again with &), then subtracting 1 from the pointer.

Comment: Why aren't you using `+stringWithUTF8String:`? `-initWithCString:` expects ASCII input, not Unicode.

Comment: ...initWithCString: takes an encoding arg for a reason.

Comment: @ CodaFi: if I write [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:c[i-1]
it get error and Xcode suggest me to add "&" front c[i-1].

Comment: This is rediculous.  Use the literal, and call `-substringToIndex:` instead of this.